# PHP cron job command not found

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to create a cron job in my shared hosting service. I have write the command:

```
0 0  * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/bdacademichelp/public_html/medcino/testSchedule.php
```

But I am getting the "command not found" message in my E-mail. what is the wrong with this command?

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/bin/php -q /home/bdacademichelp/public_html/medcino/testSchedule.php` directly on the command line?

Comment: What command does it say isn't found?

Comment: /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: 0: command not found

Comment: Plenty of hits for that error and could be of many possible reasons.

Comment: what are the reasons? Fred

Comment: "what are the reasons? Fred" eatspopcorn.jpg

Comment: ^ pretty much..

Comment: *"what are the reasons?"* - Could be a permissions issue, could be a bad path, it could be anything. You need to Google the error and find out why it's failing. There are too many possible reasons as to why it failed.

Comment: Your cronjobs are running in a jail, and not as the user <your_username>.  The jailed user doesn't have /usr/bin in its path, according to the message.  Given that the script is "in jail", it might be more likely to be a permission/privilege issue.

Comment: can you suggest any solutions for this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't put the command in the `crontab` file, you just put it into a shell script.

Comment: I have put the command in my cpanel cronjob command line

Comment: does that file exist and what is it trying to execute? Remember that if on a \*NIX system, filenames are case-sensitive `testSchedule.php` and `testschedule.php` are totally different. The question is too unclear.

Comment: the filename is correct and the file also exists

Comment: This is a never ending cycle, shall we just admit that it's a CLI fault due to us briefly reading 'command not found' and migrate it to our good friends at superuser ? If it comes back. Well apologise for our oversight and give them a basket of mini muffins? -message will tr

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to run in the terminal this part of your command:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/bdacademichelp/public_html/medcino/testSchedule.php
```

¿The cron job is running? what happened?